# Cumulative total by group in Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

After googling for two pages, I'm struggling to find a simple way to create a cumulative sum measure by date and item in Power BI (using DAX). I have a table which contains:

- Username
- Date (DD-MM-YYYY)
- Number of requests in that day

I have managed to obtain the cumulative sum by using the following expression (extracted from DAXPatterns):

```
CALCULATE (
SUM ( Table[Requests] ),
FILTER (
    ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
    'Date'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
)
)
```

But I would like to obtain a measure indicating how many requests have been made by a user up to a certain date.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: That measure looks right. If you build a report and include it and filter to user1 and 2016-12-31 you should get the requests by that user up to and including 2016. Or put date on rows and you should see the cumulative total more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create calculated table using SUMMARIZECOLUMNS function and apply filter that you need on the top of that calculated table.

```
YourCalcTableName =
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'UsernameTable'[Username],
    'Date'[Date],
    "Number Of Requests", SUMX ( 'UsernameTable', 'UsernameTable'[NumberOfRequests] )
)
```

This calculated table essencialy produces 3 column table with user name, date and number of requests sent by this user on this date.

[SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163696.aspx)